# How to find which packages are slow to load in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, configuration, package

I want to reduce the startup time of Emacs, so I'd like to find the time taken by different part of my `.emacs` file. How could I do that efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an Emacs package made exactly to monitor the execution time of `.emacs`: it's [ESUP](https://github.com/jschaf/esup) (Emacs StartUp Profiler).